# Is this sentence wrong: "This method engages students participations..."

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence wrong:

"This method engages students participations in class and create a friendly atmosphere in class, through which improve the relationship between the students and I. "

Comment: "This method engages students and encourages their participation in class."  And I'd end the sentence there and put the rest in a following sentence, since it getting to be "run-on".  Something like "We also find that this encourages a friendly atmosphere in class and improves the relationship between students and teachers."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct form would be as follows:

**"This method engages students' participation and creates a friendly atmosphere in class, which improves the relationship between me and the students."**

The subject ("method") is singular in the first clause. You would write "between me and the students" because "me" is the object of the preposition "between."